# Bluemix Single Sign on for a mobile app

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I'm adding a login page for my mobile app, so that it integrates with Bluemix Single Sign On. I'm at the step to configure the Node.js app following the Bluemix Doc at [Configuring a Node.js app](https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SingleSignOn/configure_apps.html#tsk_configuringnodejsapp_express4). The example here about callback is for a web app. In the mobile app context, I don't have a redirect URL. So this code for example:

`app.get('/auth/sso/callback',function(req,res,next) {...}`

On the mobile client side, do I do a GET to `/login`?

I already have a login implemented using Mobile Client Access service. Is it something I can build up upon? For example,

`app.post('/apps/:tenantId/:realmName/handleChallengeAnswer', function(req, res {...}`

Can I call the Single Sign On API in here?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Jen

Answer (score 1):

Is your mobile application based on nodejs? If so and you use a webview on your mobile application you could leave to the webview component to manage your authentication flow like working with a browser.
You instead have to manage authentication if your application is integrating with Rest  APIs, in this case you could use SSO but your application has to manage cookies like a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Bluemix Single Sign On so far has only been tested on web applications. I have no knowledge on whether Single Sign On would work smoothly on mobile applications.

Also, the Bluemix Single Sign On follows the OIDC protocol. So the redirect URL is a mandatory parameter when using the service, unfortunately.

Regarding building upon your login implementation, to my knowledge, it is not possible to include your implemented login in place of what is provided with the Single Sign On service. But you can choose to add the login implementation in addition to the login needed when using Single Sign On.

Hope that addresses your questions.